# output of "s = "0123456789" print(s[2:-1:-1])" slice operator

Tags: python-3.x

```
s = "0123456789"
print(s[2:-1:-1])
```

according to me, output of the above question should be "210" BUT it gives nothing
please explain to me how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python reverse-stride slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798136/python-reverse-stride-slicing)

Comment: `print(s[2::-1])` can give you `210`. Which means `seq[low::stride]      # [seq[low], seq[low+stride], ..., seq[-1]    ]` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509377/2767755).

Comment: @ggorlen This is not the exact duplicate, as it is not telling why the output is `210`.

Comment: The output isn't 210 though. I think it's a helpful link even if it doesn't get closed out. If I can read [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/sliceobject.c) I'll post an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax:
sequence [start:stop[:step]]

- **start:**

  - *Optional*. Starting index of the slice. Defaults to 0.
- **stop:**

  - *Optional*. The last index of the slice or the number of items to get. Defaults to len(sequence).
- **step:**

  - *Optional*. Extended slice syntax. Step value of the slice. Defaults to 1.

```py
+---+---+---+---+
|-4 |-3 |-2 |-1 |  <= negative indexes
+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D |  <= sequence elements
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  <= positive indexes
+---+---+---+---+
 |<- 2:-1:-1 ->|      <= extent of the slice: "ABCD"[2:-1:-1] (won't work)
```

**Explanation:**

Here in my example `"ABCD"[2:-1:-1]` If we interpret it, then it says:

1. start from index 2. (**include** that item)
2. Go till index -1 (**exclude** that item) which is the last item as you can see the table above.
3. With steps of -1 which basically means in reverse direction. Here you are contradicting your sequence. So it returns nothing.

So the solution would be `"ABCD"[2::-1]` as someone correctly answered in the comment. This says start from index 2 go till end either beginnig or end based on the steps which is -1 here so beginning.

So same answer to your question `print(s[2::-1])` will print `210`

Comment: My pleasure! 