# Unable to understand Python negative string slicing

Tags: python, string

Why doesn't it reverse the string when we put some numbers in start and stop parameters?

Example:

```
name = "i am a student"
print(name[0:14:-1])
```

does not reverse the string

Comment: what is your expected output? Are you intended to do partial reverse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python reverse-stride slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798136/python-reverse-stride-slicing)

Answer (score 0):

In this line `name[0:14:-1]` in `14th` position there is nothing in the string. slice notation is:

```
[ <first element to include> : <first element to exclude> : <step> ]
```

If you want to include the first element when reversing a list, leave the middle element empty, like this:

```
name = "i am a student"
s = name[::-1]
print(s) # output tneduts a ma i
```

please add your expected output with the post.

you can also check this post [Python reverse-stride slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798136/python-reverse-stride-slicing)

also this article https://www.jquery-az.com/ways-reverse-string-python-reversed-extended-slice-objects/