# How to do reverse slicing in Python with a variable end-index?

Tags: python, slice

I'd like to slice a list in reverse but shift the end-index by 1 each time to include more elements. How to include the number at index 0?

```
x = [2, 5, 8, 10]
for endIdx in [3, 2, 1, 0]:
    print(x[3: endIdx - 1: -1])


# output:
# [10]
# [10, 8]
# [10, 8, 5]
# [] 
# last output is not [10, 8, 5, 2] as desired.
```

To include the number at index 0, I can do

```
x = [2, 5, 8, 10]
for endIdx in [3, 2, 1, 0]:
    if endIdx != 0:
        print(x[3: endIdx - 1: -1])
    else:
        print(x[3::-1])
```

but clearly this requires more code just to deal with this edge case. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Specifically look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36774858/476. You either need to pass `None` for the end, or `-5`.

Comment: `x[3:endIdx - 1 if endIdx else None:-1]`