# How does Python execute string slicing?

Tags: python

Is there any kind of algorithm that you can apply to understand how Python will slice and output a sting?

I have

`a="what's up"`

And let's say I slice it like this:

`print(a[-2:-9:-1])`

So it gives me "u s'tah"

*But what exactly does Python do first and last when slicing a string?* Like, does it reverse a string first and then slice it, etc.?

Comment: All your questions (including the one you deleted just now) seem to be variations of the same theme. Perhaps retreat to reading existing materials until you have a _specific,_ _concrete_ question about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Comment: @tripleee Yes, they are. I'm just bad at putting all my requests into one precise, well-organized question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798136/python-reverse-stride-slicing?noredirect=1&lq=1) one is the closest to what I try to understand. But it seems I just don't understand the topic completely, or I'm extremely confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reference to
Python - Slicing Strings (w3schools.com)](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings_slicing.asp)

[Reversing a list using slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876998/reversing-a-list-using-slice-notation)

```
a="what's up"
print(a[-2:-9:-1]) - a[(start, end , step)]
```

- start: "u" in "what's **u**p" (position -2)
- end: "h"  in "w**h**at's up" (position -9)
- step: step in single character in reverse direction (-1)

So, the output would be "u s'tah"

```
  print(a[-2:-9:-1]) # u s'tah
    print(a[-2:-9:-2]) # usth
    print(a[-2:-9:-3]) # u'h
```