# String slicing in Python for string reversal

Tags: python, string

I want to reverse a string using slicing and initially I tried

```
string = "abcdef" 
print(string[len(string) - 1: 0: -1])
```

However this only prints up to the index 1

```
fedcb
```

So, I decided to change the slicing by changing the ending index of the slicing to -1

```
string = "abcdef" 
print(string[len(string) - 1: -1: -1])
```

I'm assuming this will print up to index 0. But this did not print any characters of the string upon running.
My question is why doesn't this work?

Comment: string[::-1] is what you need

Comment: Negative indices count from the end of the string, whether or not you want them to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python reverse-stride slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5798136/2745495)

Answer (score 1):

from the docs [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice):

```
 class slice(start, stop[, step])
```

> Return a slice object representing the set of indices specified by range(start, stop, step). The start and step arguments default to None.

you can use the `[::-1]` index to do that

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> s[::-1]
'olleh'
```

with a negative step, the index will go from `-1` to `~(len(s)-1)`, and by that I mean that the string will go from index `-1` to `0` reversed

Answer (score 1):

for your question,

```
string = "abcdef" 
print(string[len(string) - 1: -1: -1])
```

returns an empty string since it's taking the second argument as the stopping point : which is exactly the last character that's why it's empty ,

you can test it by running :

```
    string = "abcdef" 
    print(string[len(string) - 1: -2: -1])
```

it only returns the character 'f' xhich is the last character .

Now for what you're trying to achieve :  you can either use :

```
string = "abcdef" 
print(string[-1: -len(string)-1: -1])
##or 
print(string[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
string = "abcdef"
print(string[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be a Tricky one

Below is a table describing the structure for a `slice[]` operator

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -6 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | PositiveIndex |
|  | A | p | p | l | e |  |  |
| -6 | -5 | -4 | -3 | -2 | -1 | 5 | NegativeIndex |

`slice[]` operator takes in `start`, `stop` and `step`.

 We know that `stop` is excluded, so if we want to extreme values to be included in the result we can leave it empty or put a value greater than highest index

```py
>>>a='Apple'
>>>a[::]
'Apple'
>>>a[::-1]
'elppA'
>>>a[-5:-1:1]
'Appl'
>>>a[-5:5:1]
'Apple'
>>>a[4:0:-1]
'elpp'
>>>a[4:-6:-1]
'elppA'
```